# Problem passing data to thread using c under windows

Tags: c

I want to pass data to a thread using the CreateThread function.
This is all coded in a single .c file
Outside of any function I have

```
struct PipeReadThreadData
{
   LPCWSTR pipename;
   HANDLE handle;
};
```

Then inside the function creating the thread I  have

```
PipeReadThreadData data;
```

But the compiler says

```
error C2065: 'PipeReadThreadData': undeclared identifier
```

Why is it an undeclared identifier?

Comment: `struct PipeReadThreadData data;` There is no type named `PipeReadThreadData`

Comment: What does pipes have to do with CreateThread? Pipes are normally used for IPC. CreateThread has a parameter that should be used for passing data to the thread. So what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks that did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a struct you need to write

```
struct PipeReadThreadData data;
```

or typedef the struct like so

```
 typedef struct
 {
    LPCWSTR pipename;
    HANDLE handle;
 } PipeReadThreadData;
```

and then you can use it with

```
PipeReadThreadData data;
```